# The CMAKE_C_COMPILER: /usr/local/bin/cc is not a full path to an existing compiler tool

Tags: ros

I know there are a lot of similar questions on the internet but I tried everything. But nothing works Idk what I am doing wrong.

```
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    /usr/local/bin/cc

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.
```

I can find gcc, g++ files under usr/bin but in the error, it searches for the compiler on usr/local/bin.

```
set(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL TRUE)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/cc")
```

Even I changed the path in my CMake list for the compiler. Still no luck and by the way I am using ros1 and ubuntu. and I facing this error when I am trying to catkin_make my workspace.

Comment: "I've tried everything. But nothing works". What have you tried?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Which compiler/toolchain do you plan to use? For which CPU architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your script, and cannot fix that, but there is a workaround.
Create a symlink.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/cc /usr/local/bin/cc
```

Comment: Probably instead of using `ln`, it might be better to use `update-alternatives`?  While the effect might be the same, I guess it's probably better?

Comment: Better way is to remove local compiler `/usr/local/bin/cc` file and then install needed deb-packages by commands like `sudo apt-get install gcc cmake build-essential`. Stuff in `/usr/local/` usually create a mess.

Comment: @N0rbert As far as I understood, the script OP uses is looking for a local compiler, but OP does not have such a local compiler. In any case, please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: creating a symlink worked. previously i tried to copy and paste to new directory. now by symlink my problem has solved.